# Excpected identifier or '(' XCode C Pointer Function

Tags: c, xcode, function-pointers

I read here that this is one of the most annoying errors in xcode, please help:
I have a c code that I was able to compile and run on Android but not on iOS:

h file:

```
typedef int (*encoding_function)(const short * a_input, unsigned char * a_output, const int a_len);
typedef int (*decoding_function)(unsigned char * a_input, short * a_output, const int a_len);
void set_encoding_func(encoding_function a_encoding_func);
void set_decoding_func(decoding_function a_decoding_func);
```

first c file:

```
decoding_function real_decoding_func;
void set_decoding_func(decoding_function a_decoding_func)
{
    real_decoding_func = a_decoding_func;
}//- HERE IS THE ERROR!!!!!
```

second c file - NO ERROR!!!

```
encoding_function real_encoding_function;
void set_encoding_func(encoding_function a_encoding_func)
{
    real_encoding_function = a_encoding_func;
}
```

EDIT: After removing code I get an error "Expected unqualified-id".

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any error with your code.
Check that you included header file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @negaipro.

I am answering in the hope that it will help someone.
The above answer does not explain one function compiled and the other did not.
After more than a week of hiding code, putting it back and building with the command line tool I finally got an error that some files were not utf-8.

Bless Apple for a "great" complier.